# Counting Daily Active Accounts per Category

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

```
ID    Category    Category_Date
11       1            2021-01-05
12       3            2021-01-05
11       2            2021-01-18
12       2            2021-01-19
14       5            2021-02-01
.
.
.
```

where ID is the unique identifier. The category can change and the table will be updated automatically with the date of update.
What I'm trying to do is calculate the daily active accounts in each category, meaning ID 11 will be included in the daily active count for Category 1 on January 14th despite the category_date being the 5th and will be in the daily count of category 2 on January 30th despite the new category date being 18th.

In the end, I would like the table to look like this:

```
Date           1     2    3   4   5  6
2021-01-15    100   102  95  14  78  64
2021-01-16     98   104  96  17  81  60
...
2021-02-05    154   17  158  64  79   12
```

I tried using COUNT(ID) OVER(partition by category, category_date), but this gives me the number of accounts in categories that were changed/updated on the date. Is this possible to do on SQL? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you are after is calling "pivoting" or "conditional aggregation".

Comment: How can I set up the conditional count so that the id is included in the daily counts even if the date of category is different?

Answer (score 0):

you should to try use PIVOT function

[FROM - Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)